# In Flask is it possible to import views using the create_app() pattern without using Blueprints?

Tags: flask, view, python-import

I have a very small Flask app that is laid out as follows:

```
tinker/
      main.py
      /my_package
              init.py
              views.py
```

When I do tinker>python main.py everything runs fine.  Here are the contents of each file:

main.py:

```
from my_package import app
app.run()
```

my_package/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from my_package import views
```

my_package/views.py:

```
from my_package import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Ola!!!!!'
```

While all the above code runs fine when I try to modify it slightly by using a a create_app() code pattern, as in the below, views.py throws the following exception:  "ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'my_package' "  Is there a way to fix the problem without using Blueprints?

main.py:

```
from my_package import create_app
app = create_app()
app.run()
```

my_package/**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from my_package import views
    return app
```

my_package/views.py:

```
from my_package import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Ola!!!!!'
```

Comment: In case you want to run the code that works, you can access it from a repo I have at: https://github.com/lfernandez55/3200_importing_views_without__blueprints_examples/tree/master/Importing_views_package

Answer (score 1):

You import the views within application context, then in the views you can use current_app.

in `mypackage/__init__.py`:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import views
```

in `mypackage/views.py`:

```
from flask import current_app

@current_app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello, world!'
```

Answer (score -1):

init.py needs to be renamed to `__init__.py`

Move `app = Flask(__name__)` outside of the `create_app` method

Change to `from . import app` in **views.py**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's true that sticking the app=Flask(__name__) outside the create_app method works.  But then it's no longer following the create_app pattern at least as that pattern is modeled in https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User-starter-app/blob/master/app/__init__.py  or in Michael Grinberg's codebase that accompanies his book on Flask: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/__init__.py) always puts the app= Flask(__name__).  In the above examples app=Flask(__name__) is always inside the create_app.

Comment: Of course it does beg the question what are the advantages of the create_app pattern in the first place.  Should it always wrap the app=Flask(__name__) line?  Or is it ok to depart from the example?

Comment: BTW my __init__.py does contain the underscores.  It looks like StackOverflow is stripping out the underscores (unless they are tagged as code?)

Comment: it's because of the way its structured. miguelgrinberg uses blueprints to import each of the module's routes, whereas you need to reference **app** to add your routes. It needs to be outside the method for you to reference it

Comment: I do understand that by wrapping the app=Flask(name) in create_app it's no longer accessible to the routes.  And I get that Grinberg's create_app pattern is ok wrapping it inside the create_app because he's using Blueprints instead.  (Although, incidentally, Blueprints don't require that they be wrapped in create_app as in this example:  https://riptutorial.com/flask/example/22103/a-basic-flask-blueprints-example.)  I guess my question is that if one has to depart from Grinberg's pattern in order to import views without Blueprints is anything else being compromised?  Like perhaps scalabiity?